# How to manipulate 2d lists

Tags: python

I need help with working in 2d lists for my computing GCSE NEA(non examined assessment) and what I need to do is show the first letter of each song title on one line(One single song) along with the artists name for example AC/DC 'Back in Black' would be 'B i B' AC/DC

I am generally stuck on how to manipulate the array to show what I need and I've used several websites such as snakify and a few others

this is my program so far:

```
stageone=[['another one bites the dust','Queen',
           'smoke on the water','Deep Purple',
           'Stairway to heaven','Led Zeppelin',
           'Carry on wayward son','Kansas',
           'Don't stop believin','Journey']]
mainmenu=input("Welcome to the game please select an option-s for start the game,ts for top scores,ys for your scores,n for new game")
if mainmenu=='s':
  play=input("do you want to continue you last game-c or do you want to start 
  a new game-n?")
  if play=='s':
    difficulty=input("What difficulty do you want to play? you can choose 
    from; easy,medium,difficult and legend")
    if difficulty=='easy':
       print("The easy mode of this game contains five stages,each with five 
       questions")
       sure=input("Are you sure you want to play this gamemode?")
       if sure=='y':
       print(stageone)
```

I need the song to be on its own,not the whole array. And each song needs the first letter of each word not the whole word. I cannot figure out how to code this part of my program and help would greatly be appreciated. The song artist name however needs to be whole not single,first letter like the song title

Comment: Your list of songs is not proper syntax. You can't use non-escaped single quote marks inside a string which is enclosed by single quote marks. Use `"Don't stop believin"` rather than `'Don't stop believin'`

Comment: Also if you wish to access one song from the list use an index stageone[0][1]. This would print 'another one bites the dust'. Had to use [0][1] as u have a list in a list

Comment: Also since the songs are to be coupled with the artists why not use a list of tuples like [('another one bites the dust','Queen'),('smoke on the water','Deep Purple') .. and so on ]

Comment: Also -- in what sense is your list 2-D? You seem to have a pointless 2-D list where the outer list contains nothing but a single list. It would make more sense to have something like `stageone=[['another one bites the dust','Queen'], [ 'smoke on the water','Deep Purple'], ... ]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you define stageone, make it a list of lists like this:

`stageone = [[title, band], [title, band], [title, band]]`

then, instead of `print(stageone)` in the last line do:

```
for entry in stageone:
    shortTitle = ' '.join([word[0] for word in entry[0].split(' ')])
    print(shortTitle, entry[1])
```

---

Update: To get one hint at a time you'll need some method to select an entry out of `stage one` (for a game, I imagine this might be a random index). Then you just remove the `for` loop I gave before and use your selected entry like so

```
i = #some code to select an entry in stageone
entry = stageone[i]
shortTitle = ' '.join([word[0] for word in entry[0].split(' ')])
print(shortTitle, entry[1])
```

Note that there are a bunch of ways to make this more compact, but the original question makes me think a more verbose answer is better than a minimal solution. For instance, @calestini commented a one-liner to replace the `for` loop in my first response,

```
res = [[' '.join([x[0] for x in i[0].split()]), i[1]] for i in stageone ]
```

That's a fine solution - `res` will be a list like `[[song hint, band name], [song hint, band name]]` and then you print hints however you want. I'm not changing my original answer because I prefer not to use two list comprehensions in one line (I have a hard time reading the code).

Comment: Or with one liner `res = [[' '.join([x[0] for x in i[0].split()]), i[1]] for i in stageone ]`

Comment: @dshort  The line of code you have shown me has worked within my code and has been really helpful,thank you. But with my game you have to guess the song title. using your code how would I be able to only show one at a time?

Comment: answer updated to reflect comments from @calestini and OP